# Colocar elementos de tabla con Array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, array, script

Estoy intentando hacer un array de 10 nombres, en el cual los coloco y con el boton "Mostrar Tabla" me muestra los 10 nombres, y el botón "Generar Equipos" me los genera al azar, diviendolos en equipos cada 5 personas, pero el problema es que en el el "Team 1" me lo genera bien indicando las 5 personas, pero cuando quiero generar el "Team 2" me genera una sola fila con los 5 elementos uno al lado del otro, he estado probando varias cosas sacando el "" y el "" pero no llego a la solucion, no entiendo como deberia ser la forma correcta para que me los divida a los 5 elementos en el Team 1, y los otros 5 elementos en el Team 2 con los elementos bien posicionados.

```
var tabla = [
{nombre: "Juan"},
{nombre: "Pedro"},
{nombre: "Raul"},
{nombre: "Simon"},
{nombre: "Franco"},
{nombre: "German"},
{nombre: "Lautaro"},
{nombre: "Emi"},
{nombre: "Maxi"},
{nombre: "Lucas"}
];
var j,x,i;
var pval;
window.onload = cargarEventos;
function cargarEventos(){
    document.getElementById("mostrar-tabla").addEventListener("click", mostrarTabla, false);
    document.getElementById("cambio-nombres").addEventListener("click",cambiarNombres,false);
}  
function mostrarTabla(){
  var cuerpoTabla = document.getElementById("equipos-tabla");
  var tablaLlena = "";
  for (var i =0; i< tabla.length; i++){
      tablaLlena += "<tr><td>"+ tabla[i].nombre;
     

 
}

    cuerpoTabla.innerHTML = tablaLlena;
}

function cambiarNombres (tablaLlena) {
for (i= tabla.length -1; i>0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
    x=tabla[i].nombre;
    tabla[i].nombre=tabla[j].nombre;
    tabla[j].nombre=x;
    
    }

    pval ="<tr>";
    
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pval += "<td>"+tabla[i].nombre+"</td></tr>";
    }
   
  
    
    for (i=5; i<10; i++) {
        pval += "<td>"+tabla[i].nombre+"</td>";
    }
   
   

    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML=pval;

}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
               <div id="tabla-clasificacion"></div>
               <table class="table">
                  
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Equipos</th>
                           <th>Puntos</th>
                       </tr>
                       <tbody id="equipos-tabla">
                      
                       </tbody>
                   </thead>
               </table>

               <button id="mostrar-tabla">Mostrar Tabla</button>
               <button id="cambio-nombres">Generar Equipos</button>
               <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Team 1</th>
                        <th>Team 2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody id="pText">
                   
                    </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
               <div></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   

    <script src="js/cargarTabla.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes agregar dos 'td' por cada 'tr' asiendo referencia a los cabeceras de 'Team 1' y 'Team2'.

```html
 <table>
 <th>Team 1</th><th>Team 2</th>
 <tbody>
 <tr><td>name1 T1</td><td>name1 T2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>name2 T1</td><td>name2 T2</td></tr>
 <tbody>
 </table>
```

Para lograrlo en el ciclo `for` puedes tener nos variables, una que vaya del *inicio a la mitad* y otro que se dirija del *final a la mitad*.

```
for (i=0, j=tabla.length-1; i < tabla.length/2 ; i++, j--) {
       pval += "<tr>"
       pval += "<td>"+tabla[i].nombre+"</td>"
       pval += "<td>"+tabla[j].nombre+"</td>"
       pval += "</tr>"
}
```

El codigo completo seria así:

```js
var tabla = [
{nombre: "Juan"},
{nombre: "Pedro"},
{nombre: "Raul"},
{nombre: "Simon"},
{nombre: "Franco"},
{nombre: "German"},
{nombre: "Lautaro"},
{nombre: "Emi"},
{nombre: "Maxi"},
{nombre: "Lucas"}
];
var j,x,i;
var pval;
window.onload = cargarEventos;
function cargarEventos(){
    document.getElementById("mostrar-tabla").addEventListener("click", mostrarTabla, false);
    document.getElementById("cambio-nombres").addEventListener("click",cambiarNombres,false);
}  
function mostrarTabla(){
  var cuerpoTabla = document.getElementById("equipos-tabla");
  var tablaLlena = "";
  for (var i =0; i< tabla.length; i++){
      tablaLlena += "<tr><td>"+ tabla[i].nombre; 
  }
  cuerpoTabla.innerHTML = tablaLlena;
}

function cambiarNombres (tablaLlena) {
for (i= tabla.length -1; i>0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
    x=tabla[i].nombre;
    tabla[i].nombre=tabla[j].nombre;
    tabla[j].nombre=x;
    
    }
    pval ="";
    for (i=0, j=tabla.length-1; i < tabla.length/2 ; i++, j--) {
        pval += "<tr>";
        pval += "<td>"+tabla[i].nombre+"</td>"
        pval += "<td>"+tabla[j].nombre+"</td>"
        pval += "</tr>"
    }
    document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML=pval;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
               <div id="tabla-clasificacion"></div>
               <table class="table">
                  
                   <thead>
                       <tr>
                           <th>Equipos</th>
                           <th>Puntos</th>
                       </tr>
                       <tbody id="equipos-tabla">
                      
                       </tbody>
                   </thead>
               </table>

               <button id="mostrar-tabla">Mostrar Tabla</button>
               <button id="cambio-nombres">Generar Equipos</button>
               <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Team 1</th>
                        <th>Team 2</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody id="pText">
                   
                    </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
               <div></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   

    <script src="js/cargarTabla.js"></script>
</body>
```